# installing an example plugin in elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am new to elasticsearch, and I want to develop an elasticsearch plugin for rescoring. I was looking through the web and found an example plugin in elasticsearch repository, Expert Scoring Script (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/plugins/examples/script-expert-scoring). But I am not sure how to install this plugin and use it in the search.
Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which operating system and what type of elasticsearch installation(zip,installer, docker) you are using?

Comment: I am using macOS Catalina and using zip elasticsearch installation